# Configuring Sonar on an AWS Instance

Tags: sonarqube

I'm playing around with SonarQube on my AWS instance.
I've followed the various tutorials and have it installed and partly configured.
As its an AWS instance, I want to be able to access it remotely.
I have set the port to be 9090 and have opened up this port on AWS.
I tried leaving the "sonar.web.host" commented out and when I run Sonar it binds to 0.0.0.0:9090 and I can see it is bound (using netstat) and that it is running as a service.
However I am unable to connect to it through my browser.
I also tried specifying the actual public IP of the AWS instance in "sonar.web.host" but the sonar service dies fairly quickly with the following binding error...

2015.02.05 17:02:29 ERROR web[o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["htt...
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address /x.x.x.x:9090

Where am I going wrong with the configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a firewall issue with my AWS instance.
I switched Sonar to run on port 8080 which i had previously opened and I could access it fine.
Thanks